# Display Images MHTML

Tags: .net, httpresponse, response.write, mhtml

I have a byte array of MHTML.  When I do a Response.BinaryWrite in the Page_Load event, it displays fine.  When I do the same in a button click event, the images do not display.  I looked at the HTTP Headers in each case and only see that the button click event has the following additional headers:

Referer: http://localhost:41757/Default2.aspx
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 615
Cache-Control: no-cache

Could any of these cause the issue?  I tried doing a Response.Clear and Response.ClearHeaders, but the images still didn't display.

Thanks.